# Apple enrollment troubles

Tags: mdm, automated-device-enrollment, apple-business

So, we have never had issues with Apple automated device enrollment (we use Apple Business Manager and Intune here), however, we've suddenly run into a few issues with new devices not enrolling properly. It prompts us for a username and password (our overarching company name) when attempting to retrieve the enrollment profile. Now I've tried using all of our ABM admin account usernames/passwords (which I would presume it would be?) to no success. I had to release one device from the organisation which was the only way to get it working.

I know this may be a simple, stupid question but if anyone could advise me it would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to the company and this is just annoying as I never had this issue at my previous job which involved Apple School Manager.